Counting with trees
Let $\mathcal{U}_n$ denote the set of unrooted unlabelled trees with $n$ edges. For $T\in\mathcal{U}_n$, let $1^{u_1}2^{u_2}\cdots n^{u_n}$ be its degree distribution, that is, $u_i=\#$ of vertices having $\deg i$ so that $\sum_i u_i=n+1$ amd $\sum_i iu_i=2n$, and let $\ell(T)$ be the number of labelled trees whose underlying tree is $T$.

QUESTION. Is this true?
$$\sum_{T\in\mathcal{U}_n}\, \ell(T)\cdot 1!^{u_1}2!^{u_2}\cdots n!^{u_n}=n!\cdot \frac1{2n+1}\binom{3n}n.$$

Remark. Hence, $n$-edge trees on the left correspond to $3n$-edge trees on the right.
My thanks goes to Sam Hopkins, Ilya Bogdanov and Fedor Petrov for instructive and beautiful ideas for the variety of proofs. These help every reader.

Let me complete Sam Hopkins' answer.
The expression on the left is
$$
  \Psi\left(\sum_{i_1+\dots+i_{n+1}=n-1}{n-1\choose i_1,\dots,i_{n+1}}\prod_j x_j^{i_j+1}\right)\\
  =\sum_{i_1+\dots+i_{n+1}=n-1}{n-1\choose i_1,\dots,i_{n+1}}\prod_j(i_j+1)!\\
  =(n-1)!\sum_{i_1+\dots+i_{n+1}=n-1}\prod_j (i_j+1)
  =(n-1)!\sum_{a_1+\dots+a_{n+1}=2n}\prod_j a_j.
$$
Now the identity is a partial case of the following:
$$
  \sum_{a_1+\dots+a_k=\ell}\prod_j a_j={\ell+k-1\choose 2k-1}, \qquad(*)
$$
as
$$
  n!\frac1{2n+1}{3n\choose n}=\frac{(3n)!}{(2n+1)!}=(n-1)!{3n\choose 2n+1}.
$$
The general identity $(*)$ follows immediately from the generating functions identity $((1-x)^{-2})^k=(1-x)^{-2k}$.
A more direct proof of $(*)$: both parts equal to the number of ways of choosing $2k-1$ elements from the string of $\ell+k-1$ ones, and paint them alternatively in red and blue. The $k-1$ blue elements serve as separators dividing the other $k$ elements into the groups of $a_1,\dots,a_k$ elements.

Here's a start. Your claim is equivalent to (and easier to understand as)
$$ \sum_{T} \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} d_i(T)! = n! \, \frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{3n}{n}$$
where the sum is over all labeled trees $T$ on vertex set $[n+1]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$ and $d_i(T)$ is the degree of vertex $i$ in $T$.
Recall that the (generalized) Cayley formula says that
$$ \sum_{T} x_1^{d_1(T)}x_2^{d_2(T)}\cdots x_{n+1}^{d_{n+1}(T)} = x_1x_2\cdots x_{n+1} (x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1})^{n-1}$$
where again the sum is over all labeled trees $T$ on $[n+1]$ and $d_i(T)$ is as before.
Hence, defining the differential operator $\Psi$ by
$$ \Psi = \sum_{(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n+1})\vDash 2n} \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots \partial x_{n+1}^{\alpha_{n+1}}}$$
where the sum is over all compositions $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n+1})$ of $2n$ satisfying $1 \leq \alpha_i \leq n$ for all $i$, your claim becomes
$$\Psi(x_1\cdots x_{n+1} (x_1+\cdots+x_{n+1})^{n-1}) = n!\,\frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{3n}{n}.$$
This last expression at least avoids any discussion of trees.

It turns out that this has been considered before: https://oeis.org/A001763

@MartinRubey are you sure that’s the same? That looks like weighting each vertex by degree, not degree factorial

you are right, that's odd.

I have to stop right now, but I think it's because in the OEIS referernce we have plane trees.  Thus, we first choose a cyclic order of the neighbours of each vertex first, and then additionally a colour for the vertex itself.

Another way to find the value of the sum
$$
S:=\sum_{T} \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} d_i(T)! 
$$
using Cayley formula
$$
\sum_{T} x_1^{d_1(T)}x_2^{d_2(T)}\cdots x_{n+1}^{d_{n+1}(T)} = x_1x_2\cdots x_{n+1} (x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1})^{n-1}
$$
is using not differentiating, as in the proof by Sam Hopkins and Ilya Bogdanov, but integrating: if you want to get $d!$ from $x^d$, you multiply by $e^{-x}$ and integrate from 0 to $\infty$. That said, we get $$S=\int_{[0,\infty)^{n+1}}
x_1x_2\cdots x_{n+1} (x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1})^{n-1}e^{-x_1-x_2-\ldots-x_{n+1}}dx_1dx_2\ldots dx_{n+1}.$$
To find this integral, denote $$I_k=\int_{[0,\infty)^{n+1}}
x_1x_2\cdots x_{n+1} (x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1})^{k}e^{-x_1-x_2-\ldots-x_{n+1}}dx_1dx_2\ldots dx_{n+1},$$
so, $S=I_{n-1}$. Using a natural change of variables $x_1+\ldots+x_{n+1}=y$,
$x_1=t_1y$, $x_2=t_2y, \dots, x_n=t_ny$ we get $$I_k=\int_{0}^\infty dy\cdot e^{-y} y^{k+2n+1}\int_{t_i>0,t_1+\ldots+t_n<1}t_1\ldots t_n(1-t_1-\ldots-t_n)dt_1\ldots dt_n\\=(k+2n+1)!C,$$
where $C$ is some integral not depending on $k$. Since $I_0=(\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}dx)^{n+1}=1$, we get $C=1/(2n+1)!$ and therefore $$S=I_{n-1}=\frac{(3n)!}{(2n+1)!}=n! \, \frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{3n}{n}.$$

Well, and for what it worth an elementary proof. Let $\mathcal{F}_k$ denote the set of forests with $k$ trees, vertex set $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$, and one labelled root in every component. Define the weight $w(F)$ of a forest $F\in \mathcal{F}_k$ as $\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i!$, where $x_i=\deg_F(i)+\mathbf{1}(i\,\text{is a root in its component})$. Denote $s_k$ the sum of weights over $\mathcal{F}_k$. Note that $s_1=(3n+1)\times$ (your sum), since choosing a root in a fixed tree always gives a factor $\sum_i (d_i+1)=2n+(n+1)=3n+1$. I claim that $s_k=\frac{(3n-k+2)!}{(2n+1)!}{n\choose k-1}$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots,n+1$. This is obvious for $k=n+1$, so by (backwards) induction it suffices to verify $$s_k(n+1-k)=k(3n-k+2)s_{k+1}\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. We prove $(\heartsuit)$ by a double counting (of course) over the following graph, which is typical for such problems. For $F\in \mathcal{F}_k$, remove an edge, you get $k+1$ components, one of them, say $C$, without a root. Choose a root in $C$ as the only vertex of the removed edge which belongs to $C$ (another vertex of the removed edge belongs to a piece which already has a root). You get an element $\tilde{F}\in\mathcal{F}_{k+1}$, call $F$ and $\tilde{F}$ friends. Thus, each $F\in \mathcal{F}_{k}$ has $n+1-k$ friends (one friend for every edge). Thus, $$
s_k(n+1-k)=\sum_{F\in\mathcal{F}_{k},\tilde{F}\in \mathcal{F}_{k+1}\,\text{are friends}} w(F).
$$
To prove $(\heartsuit)$ it remains to prove that for fixed $\tilde{F}\in \mathcal{F}_{k+1}$ the sum of $w(F)$ over all its friends $F\in \mathcal{F}_{k}$ equals $k(3n-k+2)w(\tilde{F})$. This is easy: if $C_1,\ldots,C_{k+1}$ are components of $\tilde{F}$, $r_1,\ldots,r_{k+1}$ are their roots, then to get a friend of $\tilde{F}$ you choose an ordered pair of indices $i\ne j$ and join $r_j$ to arbitrary vertex $v\in C_j$. The weight of this forest equals $w(\tilde{F})\cdot (x_v+1)$, where $x_v$ is defined as above (for the forest $\tilde{F}$). The sum of $x_v+1$ over $C_i$ is $2(|C_i|-1)+|C_i|+1=3|C_i|-1$, and this must be multiplied by $k$, since for fixed $i$ there exist $k$ ways to choose $j$ not equal to $i$. Totally we get a factor $k(3\sum |C_i|-(k+1))=k(3n-k+2)$.
